# Adobe Air - Monitors Mouse Cursor

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I am developing an application in Adobe Air exe using two monitors, the application calculates how many monitors have the computer, and calculates using a rectangle to populate them.

So far so good, my question is why the mouse cursor has the decision to be the primary monitor.

For example: If I open the application on the left screen, the application starts on the left screen, open the application on the right screen, the application opens on the right screen.

Is there any way to prevent the mouse to make the management of the main monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Screen Class.

```
var screenList:Array = Screen.screens;

stage.nativeWindow.x = screenList[0].visibleBounds.left;
stage.nativeWindow.y = screenList[0].visibleBounds.top;
```

Comment: No problem. Anything about AS3, just ask. I don't know much but the 8 years of game development in AS helps a little bit.